# Jquery Datatable is not showing the records beyond 500 entries

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

I have created a table

```
<table id="test" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

Now i dont want to use ServerSide processing. So i made this client script given below

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"http://URL/demo",
          data:{
            codeType : '10'
          },success:function(data1){
            var dt = [];
            $.each(data1,function(i,v) {
                dt.push([data1[i].id,data1[i].id1,data1[i].id2,data1[i].id3,data1[i].id4,data1[i].id5]);
            });
            var table = $('#test').DataTable({
            "data": dt,
            "bProcessing": true,
             "aoColumns": [
                {"title":"ID", visible:false},
                {"title":"ID1"},
                {"title":"ID2"},
                {"title":"ID3"},
                {"title":"ID4"},
                {"title":"ID5"}
            ]
            });
          }
      });
```

I could get the proper data in this table. But i have 14000 records in Database but this table showing only 500 entries. Why? How can i show up all the records in the table?

Comment: 14000 records handled client-side is a lot of work for browser, resulting in a visible slow down of user experience. Why not doing it serverSide?

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, your `$.each()` loop is not finished at the time you initialise the `DataTable` (?) Use a [promise](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to ensure you are initialising only `when()` the loop is completed :

```js
$.when( 
  $.each(data1,function(i,v) {
    dt.push([data1[i].id,data1[i].id1,data1[i].id2,data1[i].id3,data1[i].id4,data1[i].id5]);
  })
).then(function() {
   table = $('#test').DataTable({
     "data": dt,
     "bProcessing": true,
     ...
   })
})
```

This will ensure that the dataTable is instantiated when and only when `$.each` is completed, regardless of 1 row, 14.000 rows or never if the browser crashes :)